# Java SonarQube: Unresolved imports/types have been detected during analysis. Enable DEBUG mode to see them

Tags: java, sonarqube

Small question regarding an issue encountered during a SonarQube analysis of a Java project please.

The code of the Java project is a simple Hello World SpringBoot application, nothing special. The SonarQube is a 9.3.

During CI/CD pipeline, I perform a Sonar analysis via the Sonar maven plugin. The analysis itself is successful.

However, reproducible 100%, I am facing this:

```
         [WARNING] 23:25:32.937 Unresolved imports/types have been detected during analysis. Enable DEBUG mode to see them.
         [DEBUG] 23:25:32.938 First 50 unresolved imports/types:
         - Aspect cannot be resolved to a type
         - Bean cannot be resolved to a type
         - Before cannot be resolved to a type
         - Components cannot be resolved to a type
         - Configuration cannot be resolved to a type
         - Contact cannot be resolved to a type
         - CountedAspect cannot be resolved to a type
         - CqlSession cannot be resolved
         - CqlSession cannot be resolved to a type
         - DefaultEndPoint cannot be resolved to a type
         - EnableAspectJAutoProxy cannot be resolved to a type
         - HttpClient cannot be resolved
         - HttpClient cannot be resolved to a type
         - HttpHeaders cannot be resolved to a variable
         - HttpProtocol cannot be resolved to a variable
         - Info cannot be resolved to a type
         - JoinPoint cannot be resolved to a type
         - License cannot be resolved to a type
         - LogManager cannot be resolved
         - Logger cannot be resolved to a type
         - MDC cannot be resolved
[...]
```

I do not understand what are those "Unresolved imports/type".

May I ask what is the issue, and how can I "resolve them please"?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These warnings are raised when our Java parser does not recognize some types and can not find them in bytecode.

Lombok, precisely, has deep impacts on bytecode (the bytecode of the annotated class does not reflect the actual code that we parse), altering the way you write Java code, and confusing our parser. Our parser requires valid compilable java code as input, and this code can not be compiled with javac “as is”.

More precisely, the annotation @__ is actually not defined anywhere, and the log field is only generated in the bytecode thanks to @Slf4j annotation.

Comment: Seems you have just copied from this source and not changed the annotation names asked by OP! https://community.sonarsource.com/t/unresolved-imports-types-have-been-detected-during-analysis/43321/6